# Print concept view in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

How to **export** (the aim is to discuss it with end users) **the concept view** from crystal reports editor (version 2008 or 2013) ?

Comment: What is 'concept view'? About discussion with end user - print few reports with actual data and present to customer, let them draw their ideas directly on paper :)

Comment: It won't fit to my case. My report have many conditionnal fields which can be viewed with a single or many prints :(.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you exactly want. (Sorry about me being not english person.) I usually have two possibilities to discuss over report layout - demonstrating it on real data or print common cases from real data and discuss/redraw printouts (preferred way). In rare cases, when there is written specification [of report layout] present, no discussion is required at all :)

Comment: We used crystal reports editor to directly discuss (i'm not english person too ;), i recognize french behind your way to write :)!)

Comment: No french here, sorry. What about printouts - you can force customers to sign these and afterwards (when they request some fields swapped or made bold or similar) you can charge them for specifications change ;) We have made our customers to cut and paste real paper printouts to satisfy their needs. But no, I haven't heard about possibility to export drafts or conceptual previews of reports in Crystal.